script to clean up video sequence and adjust params (resolution, filepath, etc)
I have the following repeating use cases where I'd like to automate several steps.
UC#1: I use a video upscaler and raster removal app that creates outputs with a much larger bit rate and therefore file size than I deem necessary to my acuity.   So I run these through a blender VE with medium quality output to the same file name (blender will add frame number as a file suffix prior to the file type suffix (like "myvideo 0000-32797.mp4").  I want the same height and width output.  I want to be sure that the start and end frames align to the left-aligned video sequence.
UC#2: I want to remove segments of a video.  Take for example a comedy sketch show, where some of the more experimental sketches bomb. So I cut out and remove one or more parts.  I then want to run a script that automates the appropriate output settings.
Since I apply these use cases many times per month, I'd like to automate as much as possible.

Hello. Please don't ask more than one question per post. Use the [edit] link below your post, to break this into multiple posts so that each focuses on a single issue. Make as many separate questions as necessary. Your question touches on two distinct workflows: resizing/re-encoding videos and removing segments from a video. To ensure clarity and better responses, please focus on a single issue per post

@HarryMcKenzie -- I think you reviewed this Q too quickly.  There is really only one point, one question: how to automate a common workflow, demonstrated by two overlapping use cases.

Here is an example script.   Let me know if you can change/add to this first attempt.
import bpy

# have all sequences selected, for gap removal
for s in bpy.context.sequences:
    s.select=True
bpy.context.scene.frame_current=0
bpy.ops.sequencer.gap_remove(all=True)

# set scene.frame_end to the largest frame_final_end of all strips
furthest_end = -1
for s in bpy.context.sequences:
    if furthest_end < s.frame_final_end:
        furthest_end = s.frame_final_end    
bpy.context.scene.frame_end = furthest_end


# find a MOVIE sequence to obtain resolution, etc:
ms = None
for s in bpy.context.sequences:
    if s.type == 'MOVIE':
        ms = bpy.types.MovieSequence(s)
        break

# set output filename
baseNameSplit = ms.filepath.split("\\")
baseNamePlusFT = baseNameSplit[len(baseNameSplit)-1]
baseName = baseNamePlusFT.split('.')[0]
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "C:\\Users\\James\\Downloads\\" + baseName + " "

# set output params to what I commonly prefer
bpy.context.scene.render.ffmpeg.format = 'MPEG4'
bpy.context.scene.render.ffmpeg.codec = 'H264'
bpy.context.scene.render.ffmpeg.constant_rate_factor = 'MEDIUM'
bpy.context.scene.render.ffmpeg.audio_codec = 'MP3'

# set resolution and be sure that the image snaps to this
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = ms.elements[0].orig_width
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = ms.elements[0].orig_height

bpy.ops.sequencer.strip_transform_fit(fit_method='FIT')

